# TypeScript: functions without interface

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface

**Is it allowed to use function props without any interface?**

I have a function with properties:

`from` - HTML Element

`to` - HTML Element

`coords` - Array [2, 2]

```
export const adjustElements = ({ from, to, coords }) => {
    let to_rect = to.getBoundingClientRect(),
        width = to_rect.width * ((coords[0] - 1) * 0.5),
        height = to_rect.height * ((coords[1] - 1) * 0.5);

    from.style.top = (to_rect.top + height) + "px";
    from.style.left = (to_rect.left + width) + "px";
}
```

But when I run the code I get following errors:

`Binding element 'from' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

`Binding element 'to' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

`Binding element 'coords' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

It happens because that I didn't add any interface to the function, but the problem is that I have a lot of functions like this, but with different parameters, so writing to everyone a new interface would be crazy... Is there a way where typescript could just stop requiring an interface for every function?

Comment: To what "interface" are you referring here?  What errors are you seeing, specifically?  Please review the guidelines for [ask] and about what makes a [mre].  It should be enough information so that others can demonstrate for themselves whatever you're seeing, so if you see "lots of errors" we can tell what they are.  The right way to resolve errors depends on the errors in question.  I could tell you to use type assertions, `any`, or `//@ts-ignore`, but I could also tell you to take the battery out of your fire alarm instead of checking for a fire.

Comment: Yes, you certainly can leave something without a specified type. But why? That is the whole point of TypeScript. If you are currently converting to TypeScript, then you might want to relax that rule.

Comment: But writing interface for every function is a little bit strange.

Comment: So could you tell please how do I do it?

Comment: I still don't see an interface being required anywhere.  You can use an anonymous type like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NDG4Vw); is that what you want?  If so I can write up an answer.

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I need!

Comment: But there is a little bit problem in how I use it...

Comment: `adjustElements({from: document.querySelector(".wheel-pointer"), to: document.querySelector(".wheel"), coords: [2, 1]  })`
- Doesn't work

Comment: @jcalz could you help, please?

Comment: What should happen if `document.querySelector(...)` returns `null`? How do you know it won't? How should the compiler know that? I'm happy to write up the answer for the original question, but we can't expand the scope of the question to everything you run into after the first thing is fixed, else the question becomes a tech support session for an individual, which isn't the point of Stack Overflow. If you have followup questions, you should ask them separately, & follow the guidelines for [ask] and making a [mre] ("doesn't work" is insufficient). [See](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/511366)

Comment: It's not a new question! You made a code, but it doesn't work, so I tell you about that. How did you fix the problem if the code doesn't work? You could simply say to me to create an empty function without any props! ( There is no difference )

Comment: I have answered your original question and even given a brief answer to the `document.querySelector()` issue.  There are two ways of looking at your comment; either it was a new question about the next thing you ran into, in which case it belongs in a new post (which is good for you, because it gives you more possible help instead of relying on just me in the comments).  Or it was something you needed for your original question, in which case you should have included in the original question as part of the [mre], so that people could test against your actual use case in advance of answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the compiler is unable to infer the types of the `from`, `to`, and `coords` variables destructured from the function parameter, it falls back to inferring [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) which is intentionally unsafe and allows you to do almost anything with no further error.  Assuming you've got [the `--strict` suite of compiler features](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strict) enabled (and you probably should) or even just [the `--noImplicitAny` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitAny) enabled, this automatic fallback to `any` will generate a warning, so that you are completely aware that the loss of type safety is happening.

---

The right thing to do is to [annotate the function parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#parameter-type-annotations) to tell the compiler what type it will be.  If you *want* to use `any` and just silence the warning, you can do so explicitly:

```
export const adjustElements = ({ from, to, coords }: any) => {
  let to_rect = to.getBoundingCleintRect(),
    width = to_rect.width * ((coords[0] - 1) * 0.5),
    height = to_rect.heigth * ((coords[1] - 1) * 0.5);

  from.style.top = (to_rect.top + height) + "px";
  from.style.left = (to_rect.left + width) + "px";
} // no error
```

but this allows all kinds of crazy calls to `adjustElements` where you'd probably want to see a compiler error:

```
adjustElements("oopsie"); // no error
```

as well as allowing crazy *implementations*; consider that in the above code I completely misspelled `getBoundingClientRect` and `to_rect.height` but the compiler failed to catch either mistake, because both `to` and `to_rect` are of type `any` and the compiler gives up on worrying what you're doing with those.

So you don't want to do that.

---

Instead, you should think about what type the function parameter must be.  You've already done this: the `from` and `to` properties should be `HTMLElement`, and the `coords` property should be a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of length two where each element is a `number`.

You could make a named [`interface`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces) for this object type, but if you're only ever going to use it once, you might not want to bother giving it an explicit name.  In that case you can just use an *anonymous* [object type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#object-types):

```
export const adjustElements = ({ from, to, coords }:
  { from: HTMLElement, to: HTMLElement, coords: [number, number] }
) => {
  let to_rect = to.getBoundingClientRect(),
    width = to_rect.width * ((coords[0] - 1) * 0.5),
    height = to_rect.height * ((coords[1] - 1) * 0.5);

  from.style.top = (to_rect.top + height) + "px";
  from.style.left = (to_rect.left + width) + "px";
}
```

Now this works and the compiler will catch misspellings, and it will also catch bogus calls to `adjustElements()`:

```
adjustElements("oopsie"); // error
// Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of 
// type '{ from: HTMLElement; to: HTMLElement; coords: [number, number]; }
```

That's an error because you gave it a `string` where it expected your anonymous object type, and a `string` is not appropriate.

---

Note that the compiler considers the following a bogus call also:

```
adjustElements({
  from: document.querySelector(".wheel-pointer"),
//~~~~ <-- Type 'HTMLElement | null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLElement'
  to: document.querySelector(".wheel"),
//~~ <-- Type 'HTMLElement | null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLElement'
  coords: [2, 1]
}) // error!
```

The errors tell you exactly the problem: the `from` and `to` properties may well be `null`, because `document.querySelector()` sometimes returns `null`.  The compiler does not know that anything of class `"wheel-pointer"` or `"wheel"` exists in the document, so it's an error. If you want to make a call like this you will need to either *check* that those aren't `null`, or *assert* that they aren't.  A check could look like this (using [truthiness narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#truthiness-narrowing)):

```
const wheelPointerElement = document.querySelector(".wheel-pointer");
if (!wheelPointerElement) throw new Error("OH NO");
const wheelElement = document.querySelector(".wheel");
if (!wheelElement) throw new Error("WHY ME");

adjustElements({
  from: wheelPointerElement,
  to: wheelElement,
  coords: [2, 1]
}) // okay
```

While an assertion could look like this: (using [the non-null assertion operator `!`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator)):

```
adjustElements({
  from: document.querySelector(".wheel-pointer")!,
  to: document.querySelector(".wheel")!,
  coords: [2, 1]
}) // okay
```

It's too far afield from the original question to explain the differences between checking and asserting, pros and cons of each, and the different ways to do them.  Just know that these error situations are part of the point of TypeScript in the first place.  In your original JavaScript code, you'd have to wait until runtime to see errors on `adjustElements(null, null, [2, 1])`.  TypeScript warns you ahead of time that something like that might happen at runtime and gives you a chance to address it.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=1&ssl=13&ssc=2&pln=12&pc=1#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBBYBPJBvAUEpEAHjAPYBOALkvCcFFSACYBWArvQKIA2EkwFUJAF4kACixIAZmRJgANEgokFNco0EBfAFxIQGAJTCAfNjz4kPKkoD6ZCPCoilAOgDmECgCESrYIwCWwK4AwjyBFABK9hSi+nJm5kgA7v6MFAAWwookttHOKWmZAFRioqpk6gDaAAwAukgAtEgAjIYl1c4ArHEJ5ukQ-q7pjtm5Ds79gxlIJaJlJGpQlc31Ta0zSB3dANw4vdKyzvToPM5KMFmiNnbj50gA1EiTQxSGjwBEMITvu4kHYEcKCcIM4eJIRlccjcKKCIOCHslUhk3khPt9fkgNHt8Ew2JweHwBKJ3gsYFB-BB3vptkgAPS0pDAEgEMgyMh7LE4IikSjUWj0XQsdgUbi8CD8QQicRSGTybIqBYVTRaMwSf46AASABUALIAGVFhIUSk1uoNBPFFAVix0lWArDAACMIGQFPanS76ljDEITLh8JZRtCsi53F4fH5AiEuBT+FEHLF4okCtMnFC8iniqVylU6o0Wm1Nl0eolnsMQ+nxmWqLN5otlqsCxsttTsTLDsdTncpdc8ndHtWUWifmZ-oDgbD4T3KzCwVRHpmh18R5zccLDZaoMTSeTKdS6QyXWycPTUGRXA7LUgSJJFOgYMgAOT0MhRx9IfyCJkMKDk1ygR0eGyJA4DIcAPBda9bxPBkgQfJBHzVWVTX1Dd+BpE0kG1VCLXQvkbSQO0HWdV1GWIz0aVXIV8TFCVxFHZCkEYEh4EvfhnAAR1YF10AAZQgHgHHIYl8n6ASGlIcIXSpJMDwAPwUuSkAAHgaJotXvJ9sPNWiqAAHzIrguHfT9GRIH8-wAoClDveDH20tCKEfMxMOY1jCU47iyD4gTomE95RIgASZLMekFJUtSkA0uyHNw-TDOMj8v3M3Rf0GKzkBsuCtLNRznPwHMoFtAAmBQVhwDRDFPI9yAAQj2HAaDoKgkjErgAAUSCkshHKyNy2JhLieP4wSlDIETWqCrgJK6-hpNbfxb1EWrJoEzruscwwMhkJJGQgXaOFZfyAHkNSQAA5Y6qV2JqBVWrhepEfqPKG7yRr88aAvu66cEWsQVrazbFHSHa9oOo7PoAdQ1ABNJAdQ4H6cDXGjCS3f12zAHR7vWuaeri2TMPuxzZMKkqytqCqqoZEgAGsQHQBqUZFOL0YY2QdGey1POG3yhM+wLxMkvGqVqwmSE5liBp5t6+bGia2tF0nFXUcmWkpyqD2venGaAA)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** As jcalz pointed out in a comment, the answer I've given isn't valid TypeScript. I had missed that you were passing a single argument wrapped in `{}` rather than passing in three separate arguments.

---

You need to tell TypeScript what the types of your function's arguments are meant to be. If you don't, and TypeScript can't tell somehow (e.g. if they had a default value), then it will infer their type as `any`. But the default compiler settings prevent [implicit any](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitAny) types.

You don't need to use an interface, you can do this:

```
export const adjustElements = ({ from: HTMLElement, to: HTMLElement, coords: [number, number] }) => {
```

Comment: [This isn't valid TypeScript](https://tsplay.dev/mZaqKN).

Comment: Ah, good point. When copy/pasting the code to edit it, I hadn't caught that it was a single argument wrapped in `{}` instead of three separate arguments.